# I need to rsync from Ora1 vpn (as user michal) and rsync files into Ora2 vpn (as user srv_data). User 'michal' is in wheel grp on both Ora1 and Ora2

Tags: ssh, rhel, rsync, synchronization, oracle-linux

Hello Unix enthusiasts.

I have two vpms called **Ora1** and **Ora2**.
I need to synchronize the contents of /DATA/ directory **from Ora1**, into the same /DATA/ directory located **on the Ora2** vpm.

Ora1 /DATA/ permissions.

```
Fri Apr 07 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ ls -lah / | grep -i 'data'
drwxrwx--x.   2 srv_data srv_data   88 Apr  4 10:14 DATA
```

Ora2 /DATA/ permissions.

```
Fri Apr 07 [michal@Ora2 ~]$ ls -lah / | grep -i data
drwxrwx--x.   2 srv_data srv_data   88 Apr  4 10:14 DATA
```

I want to perform the synchronization using `michal` user, because this is my main user I log in to both of these vpns.
But as you can see, the /DATA/ directories are owned by `srv_data` user, that has the ability to log into shell and execute commands but is not a part of 'wheel' group.
`michal` is a part of `wheel` group, as well as `srv_data` group.

Ora1 users and groups:

```
Fri Apr 07 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ groups michal
michal : michal wheel apache srv_data
Fri Apr 07 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ sudo groups srv_data
srv_data : srv_data
```

Ora2 users and groups:

```
Fri Apr 07 [michal@Ora2 ~]$ groups michal
michal : michal wheel apache srv_data
Fri Apr 07 [michal@Ora2 ~]$ sudo groups srv_data
srv_data : srv_data
```

All this needs to be working on ssh keys (which are already configured), without the need to provide passwords ever.
Of course the `ssh` connection is configured and all permissions are set as necessary: `chmod 700 .ssh` and `chmod 600 all the files in ~/.ssh/*`

```
Fri Apr 07 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ ls -lah /home/michal/.ssh/
total 20K
drwx------. 2 michal michal 137 Apr  6 15:26 .
drwx------. 4 michal michal 137 Apr  6 15:26 ..
-rw-------. 1 michal michal 237 Apr  3 09:23 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 michal michal 698 Apr  6 15:26 config
-rw-------. 1 michal michal  99 Mar 23 08:42 poczt_id_ed25519.pub
-rw-------. 1 michal michal 464 Apr  3 08:31 rsync_server_id_ed25519
-rw-------. 1 michal michal 138 Apr  3 08:31 rsync_server_id_ed25519.pub
```

```
Fri Apr 07 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ sudo ls -lah /home/srv_data/.ssh/
total 20K
drwx------. 2 srv_data srv_data 128 Apr  6 16:15 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 srv_data srv_data 159 Apr  6 16:15 ..
-rw-------. 1 srv_data srv_data 138 Apr  6 10:07 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 srv_data srv_data 700 Apr  6 16:15 config
-rw-------. 1 srv_data srv_data 174 Apr  6 11:44 known_hosts
-rw-------. 1 srv_data srv_data 464 Apr  6 09:22 rsync_server_id_ed25519
-rw-------. 1 srv_data srv_data 138 Apr  6 09:22 rsync_server_id_ed25519.pub
```

I need to use `rsync_server_id_ed25519` private key to connect.
Both `michal` and `srv_data` are able to login to both **Ora1** and **Ora2** vpn.

The end result should be all the rsynched files inside Ora2 /DATA/ directory be owned by `srv_data` user, like so;

```
total 12K
drwxrwx--x.  2 srv_data srv_data   88 Apr  4 10:14 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root     root      250 Apr  6 15:29 ..
-rwxrwx--x.  1 srv_data srv_data 1.7K Apr  4 10:14 blade_runner_the_movie_1982
-rwxrwx--x.  1 srv_data srv_data 2.2K Apr  4 10:09 mud_the_movie_2012
-rwxrwx--x.  1 srv_data srv_data   66 Apr  3 11:18 synch_test_00
```

This is what worked for me so far, but it was done from `srv_data` user and I want to rsync from `michal` user.

```
Fri Apr 07 [srv_data@Ora1 /home/michal]$ rsync -Pav -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/rsync_server_id_ed25519" /DATA/ srv_data@10.32.8
1.218:/DATA/
sending incremental file list
./
blade_runner_the_movie_1982
          1,725 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=2/4)
mud_the_movie_2012
          2,249 100%    2.14MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=1/4)
synch_test_00
             66 100%   64.45kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, to-chk=0/4)

sent 4,339 bytes  received 76 bytes  2,943.33 bytes/sec
total size is 4,040  speedup is 0.92
```

Comment: Is this even possible to do??

Comment: Do you get an error message if you try to do this as the michal user?